# AS3: Call external function periodically depending on played video stream

Tags: actionscript-3, callback, video-streaming, netstream

I implemented a flex application to play an incoming video stream from a Red5 Media Server.

```
private function playStream(streamName:String, offset:int):void {
  stream = new NetStream(connection);
  stream.play(streamName + ".flv", offset);
  var streamVideo:Video = new Video();
  streamVideo.attachNetStream(stream);
  display.addChild(streamVideo); }
```

The playStream method plays a given stream from the position which is defined by offset parameter. Now I want to update my page content depending on the played video stream. Or more specifically I want to call an actionscript method that updates the content, after each minute in the video. Should I use Timer for that reason?

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you will need to user a `Timer` object. But don't use the `Timer` to determine where the user is at in playback of the video. You should use the [time](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html#time) property of the `NetStream`  instead.

You should also add an event listener for the `NetStatusEvent` in your `playStream()` method. In particular, you want to inspect the [info](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/NetStatusEvent.html#info) property of this event (technically it's the `info.code` property). This has several useful messages that you will want to use to know: when the video playback starts/stops/pauses, when the user performs a seek, and so on. This way you can manage your `Timer` and update the UI efficiently when the user interacts w/the video player.

Some of the relevant codes on the `NetStatusEvent` are below. But inspect the full list, you might find others that will help you.

- NetStream.Pause.Notify (the user paused playback, start/stop the timer here as appropriate)
- NetStream.Play.Start (playback started, start the timer)
- NetStream.Play.Stop (playback stopped, stop the timer)
- NetStream.Seek.Notify (user seeked to a new point, update the UI)